# Where is .bashrc file found in Linux?

Tags: bash, kali-linux, bashrc, profile

I am not finding my .bash_login and .bash_profile

```
root@linux:~# locate .bash*
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc.original
/home/noroot/.bashrc
/home/noroot/.bashrc.original
/root/.bash_history
/root/.bashrc
/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc
/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/bash.bashrc
/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/skel/dot.bashrc
/usr/share/kali-defaults/.bashrc
root@linux:~#
```

Is there always only one .bashrc and .bash_profile file for every user?

And, is .bashrc and .bash_profile always found in the /home/"user name" directory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only ones that bash looks at by default are in the user's home directory, yes. There is also typically a single source for them in Linux -- /etc/skel. The user's home directory does not need to be under /home, though.

I see you've edited your question to ask where your .bash_login and .bash_profile files are. Based on the `#` prompt, I'm going to assume you're running this as root. In that case, your files are

```
/root/.bash_history
/root/.bashrc
```

See my original answer above regarding a user's home directory -- it's not always /home; in this case, root's home directory is `/root`.

Answer (score 15):

According to `man bash`:

> When  bash  is  invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option,
>   it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for
>   ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

```
~/.bash_profile
    The personal initialization file, executed for login shells

~/.bashrc
    The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
```

There is also **`/etc/bashrc`** (**`/etc/bash.bashrc`** in Debian-based Linux) which contains `System wide functions and aliases`. By default, this is set, even for non-interactive, non-login shells.

**EDIT:**

The `tilde` in the paths indicates the `home directory` of the currently logged in user.  Bash is only able to use one of `~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile` (per currently logged in user), in that order, for reading and executing commands.  (Debian-based operating systems typically do not have `~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login.`  They use the file `~/.profile`.  This file explains that it will be read and used unless `~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login` are created.

> `#~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.`
>
> `#This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login`
>   exists.

Comment: In which way does this answer my question?

Comment: @BROY It answers the question you *should* have been asking rather than the one you did.

Comment: I have seen some people put a .bash_profile file in project directories, does that really get picked up by bash? I don't think that's supposed to happen by default.

Answer (score 10):

Your `bashrc` file's location is distro-dependent. Here is a basic list for the system `bashrc`:

- `/etc/bashrc` (Redhat, Fedora, etc)
- `/etc/bash.bashrc` (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Backtrack, Kali etc)
- `/etc/bash.bashrc.local` (Suse, OpenSuse, etc)

Then there is the private single-user `bashrc`, which, for the most part is stored in `~/.bashrc` for basically every distro... If you do not have one of the distros listed, or have a special system, you can always look up `bashrc` location on google for that distro or system...

Comment: Note that on SLES (at least SLES 15 where I checked), the system `bashrc` is `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which *itself* sources `/etc/bash.bashrc.local`.

Answer (score 1):

As people have already stated, you can find a skeleton of bashrc in /etc/skel/.bashrc. If different users want different bash configurations then you must put a .bashrc file in that users home folder.

When it comes to .bash_profile and .bash_login, the user needs to create those manually and link them via bashrc. bash_profile and bash_login exist to create a more organised feel for the different settings you load. I personally keep all of my aliases in bash_profile so I do not have to sort through a mess in bashrc to make a quick edit.

Here is an example of what you would have in your .bashrc file:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
        . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```