# How to remove path from terminal prompt in Debian?

Tags: bashrc

From command line, long directory paths can take up the entire line:

[image: long working directory path]

Similar questions have been asked:

1. [Hides directory path in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16728/hide-current-working-directory-in-terminal)
2. [Remove "PWD" from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220228/how-do-i-remove-pwd-from-terminal)
3. [Remove full path from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232086/remove-full-path-from-terminal)
4. Show [only current directory name on bash prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/60555/show-only-current-directory-name-not-full-path-on-bash-prompt)

Steps taken:

- [Locate the .bashrc file in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211879/287606)  `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- From /etc directory in terminal: `sudo gedit bash.bashrc`
- Find the line: `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`
- Change lowercase 'w' to an uppercase 'W' (in bold):

> PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\ **W**\$ '

- Save (as sudo) and [reload the .bashrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518150/5270462) solves the problem temporarily but not in new terminal window. The colors change, too (the green and blue gets knocked out and all text turns white)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have your own `PS1` definitions in `~/.bashrc` (unless you are root) overriding the system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc` (which is without colors). You should edit `PS1` there.

In my `~/.bashrc` the `PS1` stuff looks like this (default Debian stretch):

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

The first definition is the one with colors. Change `\w` to `\W` in your `~/.bashrc` and you should be good.

Comment: That's exactly what it was.  Thanks for the direction.